# Change the colors of the features

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I've developed an application on `Vue JS` which loads the services from the `ArcGIS Server` via `REST API`.

When I load a service by the URL `http://arcgis/.../query?f=json&outFields=*`, the layers are added with a given color.

Is there a way to change the color of the features on the map, without editing on the server? It's done somehow [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=65c1d56a2b194e02937bc702d98e2b73) via the `Change style` option.

Now I'm solving this by adding the polygons with chosen colors on the features, however, this is awful regarding the performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change WMS symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83247/change-wms-symbology)

Comment: The `query` operation returns features only, no colors. Whatever color you see is determined by the client software you are using. If you tell us what that software is, someone might be able to help you. Another thing: In the query you specified `returnGeometry=false`, meaning only the attributes are returned. So even _with_ color information, there is nothing to draw.

Comment: @1saac ArcGIS Server via REST API isn't a WMS so the question is not a duplicate

Comment: View the source on this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/renderer_unique_value/

Comment: Loaded features in an application, right? Check out the source code of the map in the link. Is changing the colors of loaded features.

Comment: @enolan Looks like there are just polygons used. These are not service layers.

Comment: Did you see http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/about-dynamic-layers.htm? If your layer are defined as dynamic, you should be *"Determining which layers will appear in a map, layer symbology, layer order and position, labeling, and more, can be achieved on the server through the use of dynamic layers. In this way, dynamic layers can increase the amount of interaction that users are able to have with your maps."*

Comment: The answer below manipulates a Feature Server's properties, which is a different story than just changing the **look** of your layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can transform the properties of a REST service via GET. You can update the drawingInfo of a feature service using Update Definition via POST:

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/update-definition-feature-layer-.htm

Example 3 shows how the post body will be formatted. For example: `{ "drawingInfo": {
  "renderer": {
   "type": "uniqueValue",
   "field1": "symbolid",
   "field2": null,
   "field3": null,
   "fieldDelimiter": ", ",
   "defaultSymbol": null,
   "defaultLabel": null,
   "uniqueValueInfos": [
    {
     "symbol": {
      "type": "esriSLS",
      "style": "esriSLSSolid",
      "color": [
       0,
       0,
       0,
       255
      ],
      "width": 2
     }
....`

The JSON response will be related to the update definition request itself. So, 'Success' : true. You will need to capture the JSON of the layer, modify the color property and send the entire body with your changes. See this URL for an example: https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Wildfire/FeatureServer/2

Comment: Do you administer the service? If so, you should consider the Edit Service function: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/enterprise-administration/server/editservice.htm

Comment: I don't want to edit on the server. Does this approach edit on the server?

Comment: Yes, both options edit the properties of the service on a server. You should modify your question to include more information regarding ' load a service ' and ' user side '. What language or framework are you using to load your service and make client-side modifications?

Comment: I showed an example from `arcgis.com` in the question, which changes the colors on the user side only (via the `Change style` option)

Comment: 1) Create a FeatureLayer using ESRI's Javascript API
2) Apply the renderer property to your feature layer, as suggested by @enolan
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#data-visualization

Comment: I checked the last link in your answer (arcgis.com). I changed the color of the feature using the `Change style` option. It changed only on user side (after F5 the initial colors returned). So, it doesn't change on server side, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Styling changes made in an ArcGIS Online map using the Change Style feature only apply to the map, not the layer properties on the server.

Comment: But that's exactly what I need. I showed this example in the question. So, how to implement `Change style`?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any other way to intrepret your request other than you are looking for a client side operation. 
"Is there a way to change the color of the features on the user side, without editing on the server?"
You can send this discussion to chat if you like. At this point I am unsure how to help you.

Comment: Change Style is a user interface tool within ArcGIS Online's Map product. There is no unique API to this product, nor is there a function within the javascirpt API called 'ChangeStyle'. You will need to use the javascript functions I have discussed to make modifications to the feature layer. 
See more information about the UI functionality here: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/change-style.htm