# Cannot read pixel value from DTM raster with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, pixel, z-value

I am using this DTM:
http://ags.cuzk.cz/arcgis2/services/dmr4g/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

At ArcGIS I am able to ready pixel value of the raster but at QGIS it doesn't work. Tried this plugins to get the value

- Point sampling tool
- Value Tool
- Profile tool

But the layer looks empty, like no pixel value in there (at ArcGIS there are).

Can anybody try me link to confirm same issue with layer? Maybe I do something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you cannot access the values from this DTM is because it is being served as a WMS, which QGIS is unable to obtain data from.

Sometimes some WMS work as WFS if this one does, the second answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310302/how-can-i-extract-features-from-a-wms-layer-in-qgis.) might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you use WMS layer which can be served like a tiled image - not "real" DTM. Why not to use SRTM or EU-DEM?

SRTM
http://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/

EU-DEM
https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/copernicus-land-monitoring-service-eu-dem

This is an example of using EU-DEM data. I cropped some part using a polygon layer in SAGA-GIS and then applied custom styling in QGIS (nothing difficult). It is native offline dataset so I can perform various operations with it:

[image: EU DEM example]