# Make color transparent

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-3, transparency-opacity, copernicus

I've downloaded some maps from copernicus, e.g. this map: http://marine.copernicus.eu/services-portfolio/access-to-products/?option=com_csw&view=details&product_id=BALTICSEA_ANALYSIS_FORECAST_BIO_003_007

I want to maps to be shown on top of each other, but I can't make the colors transparant.

[image: The "top" map]
[image: The "bottom" map]

I only want to show the arrows from the "top map", Is there a way to make the gray part transparent?

When I look under symbology I can't choose anything else than single band color. 
[image: Symbology]
[image: Transparency]

Comment: Hello, welcome to GIS SE. Please add a tag for what software you're using (even though it's clearly QGIS it helps to add tags). Also what format is your data in? Is it a tif that you downloaded or is it a WMS layer or something else?

Comment: Hi. It's Qgis 3.4.4. I've updated the tags. 
The data format is WMS, so the layers are connected by a html like the one I've linked to. Does this makes sense? :)

Comment: Try the different blending modes, which I believe are called "blandingstilstand" in your version. Or increase the contrast and make the layer partially transparent. You should be able find a combination where both layers are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is being served to your project as a WMS the symbology cannot be changed, have a look at [Change WMS symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83247) to see if there is anything you can do to make your life easier.

If you find a way to download the data, then in the Transparency tab of the layer properties you can add No Data values under Custom Transparency Options. Use the second button on the right hand side to take samples of the colours that you do not want displayed and add them to the list No Data values. You might need to do this a few times to exclude everything that you don't want.